# How to write 'SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM TABLENAME' in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried using

```
$this->db->select("SQL_CACHE *");
$this->db->from("zone");
```

But it is translating into SELECT `'SQL_CACHE' * FROM Zone`.
I want `SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM Zone`
Codeigniter is considering **SQL_CACHE** as a column.
Please help.

Comment: Why you are passing `SQL_CACHE` with query, As codeigniter has own Mysql caching mechanism use them.

Comment: How to use them?